# Javascript Printing HTML but contents not being captured in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using this line of JS:

```
document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = 
'<input type=\"text\" id=\"name\"/>';
```

to place a textbox in a div called 'nameDiv'. When I hit submit on the form it doesn't seem to pick up the contents of this JS generated text box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must supply a `name` attribute to have it sent via the POST/GET (without JavaScripting around it, anyway).

```
document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = 
'<input type=\"text\" id=\"name\" name=\"some-name\"/>';
```

I used `some-name` for example here, you can use the most relevant `name`.

Also, why are you escaping `"` when your string delimiter is `'` and there will be no clash? I assume this is in a string somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. You're answer was right in every way possible. Thanks for the info about escaping too. I'm sure Eclipse was moaning about me now having it but it appears not to be now. Thanks.

Will accept as answer as soon as possible.